# Error calling get-wmiobject for Win32_powerplan

Tags: powershell, winapi, get-wmiobject, windows-11

I'm trying to return the [`Win32_PowerPlan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/dd904531(v=vs.85)) in PowerShell 7 on Windows 11 with the following code:

```
get-wmiobject -namespace "root\cimv2\power" -class Win32_powerplan
```

However, I get the output:

```
get-wmiobject : 
At line:1 char:1
+ get-wmiobject -namespace "root\cimv2\power" -class Win32_powerplan
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

[image: Error Log Outuput]

Not sure what could be going on or how to get better error logs.  The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/accessing-data-in-the-interop-namespace#assigning-the-power-profile-to-a-variable) use this exact code snippet, so not sure what it should change to if it's wrong.

Potentially related to [PowerShell call to Win32_PowerPlan showing invalid class error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68491063/1366033)

Comment: `Get-WmiObject` isn't available in PowerShell core. Either run it in Windows PowerShell, or  use `Get-CimInstance` as they are the cmdlets that superseded it.

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that, to retrieve the information you are seeking, PowerShell needs to be run in "elevated" mode (i.e., "Run as Administrator").

When doing so, I see the information as intended; however, when running 'normally' (even though I'm logged on with admin rights), I see the same error message that you have reported.